# A unrelated vuejs app route handled by the server?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Let's say I have a vuejs webapp: www.example.com. It uses vue-router, so there are a bunch of predefined routes: example.com/signin, /signup, /dashboard (when the user logs in), and there is also a * route that redirects to a /404 if the route is not found:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/signup',
      name: 'signup',
      component: () => import('@/views/SignIn.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/signin',
      name: 'signin',
      component: () => import('@/views/SignIn.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: () => import('@/views/Dashboard.vue'),
      beforeEnter: requireAuth
    },
    {
      path: '/404',
      name: '404',
      component: () => import('@/views/NotFound.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/404'
    }
  ]
})
```

That same website (www.example.com) will also provide an API (i.e. www.example.com/api/some-end-point). Is there a way to configure in vue-router to send the user out of the app instead of redirecting to /404?

Comment: hat do you mean by *to send the user out of the app*?

Comment: When someone types www.example.com/api/whatever in their browser, I the request to be handled by the server, and return a json (I already know how to make this happen). But any other route would be handled by the vue router. I will use express on the backend to create the api. I'm not sure how to phrase it better! I'm not experienced with vue. Basically I dont want the ./api route to be handled by the SAP, I want it to make a request to the server instead.

Comment: Oh and might be important to know, the api will not be consumed by the vue app.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend if you are in development mode or in a production build. In a development mode you can add or create a `vue.config.js` add config the `devServer`. The `devServer` you can proxy to your `api`. Let's say you are running a NodeJS or PHP app on port `3000` you can add the following to `vue.config.js`. In this setup for `npm run serve` your `http://localhost:8080/api` would route to your api.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8080,
    https: false,
    hotOnly: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000'
      }
    }
  },
}
```

If you are in production mode you are likely going to need a webserver like `NGINX` for `apache`. In Nginx for example you would need to separate the `/api` location to your api via proxy and the rest to your vue files. An example is below

```
...
      location /api {
            proxy_pass         http://myapi:3000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
            expires off;
            access_log off;
            if_modified_since off;
            add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
            proxy_no_cache 1;
        }

        location / {
            try_files /path/to/my/vue/build/files /;
        }
...
```